# How to read "params" array any one

Tags: java, android, json

In this Json how to read "params" Json. Please give me a solution to read this data. But where I get the "params" error show.

> org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"Consumer
>   ID","MinLength":11,"MaxLength":11,"FieldType":"NUMERIC","IsMandatory":true}]
>   at params of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Json

```
{"statuscode":"TXN","status":"Transaction Successful","data":[{"is_bbps_enabled":1,"payment_amt_exactness":2,"payment_mode":"Cash","payment_channel":"AGT","service_type":"ELECTRICITY","service_provider":"UPPCL (URBAN) - UTTAR PRADESH","product_info":"","provider_key":"UPE","bill_fetch":1,"is_tup":"0","is_down":"0","**params**":"[{\"name\":\"Consumer Number\",\"MinLength\":10,\"MaxLength\":12,\"FieldType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"IsMandatory\":true}]"}]}
```

I have try this..

```
     try {
                    JSONObject jsobobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    status = jsobobj.getString("statuscode");

                    if(status.equals("TXN")) {

     JSONArray jsonArray = jsobobj.getJSONArray("data");
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ){
             JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             JSONArray jsonArrayParam = jsonObject.getJSONArray("params");
               for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayParam.length(); j++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayParam.getJSONObject(j);
                   spKey_Name = jsonObject1.getString("name");

                        }
                      }

try {
                    JSONObject jsobobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    status = jsobobj.getString("statuscode");

                    if(status.equals("TXN")) {

                      JSONArray jsonArray = jsobobj.getJSONArray("data");
                      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ){
                          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                          JSONArray jsonArrayParam = jsonObject.getJSONArray("params");
                          for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayParam.length(); j++){
                              JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayParam.getJSONObject(j);
                              spKey_Name = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                              beniname = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                          }
                      }
```

Comment: which kind error?

Comment: First of all, I want to know this code is correct to get the "params" array data from above json.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: (-:  It would be correct if it would work. It depends on what do you mean "correct"

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"Consumer ID","MinLength":11,"MaxLength":11,"FieldType":"NUMERIC","IsMandatory":true}] at params of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: you are facing the error `String cannot be converted to JSONArray` because the values of `params` is `String` not `JSONArray`. Just see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can get "params" like this

```
JSONArray jobjArr=jobj.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i=0;i<jobjArr.length();i++)
    {
       JSONObject jdata=jobjArr.getJSONObject(i);

       String param=jdata.getString("params");

       JSONArray jParams=new JSONArray(param);

       JSONObject jobjParams=jParams.getJSONObject(0);
       String name=jobjParams.getString("name");

    }
```

you can get remain string from object like "name"

Answer (score 0):

The **params** is `String` not `JSONArray`. The difference is `""` before and after `[]`. You can check your json and validation from [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Your json

```
"params":"[{\"name\":\"Consumer Number\",\"MinLength\":10,\"MaxLength\":12,\"FieldType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"IsMandatory\":true}]"
```

Should be like

```
"params":[{"name":"Consumer Number","MinLength":10,"MaxLength":12,"FieldType":"NUMERIC","IsMandatory":true}]
```

So you have 2 options. First one is change in your json for get `JSONArray` or second one is get String from json and convert it to JSONArray just like that

```
String params = jsonObject.getString("params");
JSONArray jsonArrayParam = new JSONArray(params);
```